# Xamarin.iOS App crashes after showing launch screen when distributed through TestFlight

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, provisioning-profile, testflight

I'm currently working on an Application using Xamarin.iOS framework. The App runs as expected when I run it on Simulator & in iPhone using debug configuration. But, when the App is uploaded to TestFlight using a Distribution Profile, it crashes immediately after showing the Splash Screen for a second. My TestFlight users have repeatedly reported that it crashes only on TestFlight builds. Not sure why this happens?

When the build is distributed using Ad-Hoc profile, it works fine as it should.

I have tried updating MacOS, Xamarin Studio, XCode, but in vain.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: First thing you need to do is installing the problematic version in your phone and check device logs. Also check the differences between your ad-hoc and the test-flight compiler configurations. That may be a hint. It´s probably the linker skipping some assembly in the test-flight configuration

Comment: Just to discard linker issues, you could set "Don´t link" in the test-flight compiler configuration and release a build

Comment: @xleon Thanks for the prompt. I have checked the device log as suggested & found it to be a Memory leak crash. Still not sure why this happens only on testflight version and not on Ad-hoc versions.

Comment: A memory leak at the app start? that´s unlikely. What are yo doing?

Comment: @xleon I have used rich images, audio files at the start. Also, I need to delete some unused framework from my App Delegate to reduce the final IPA size. But why crash only on testflight versions?

Comment: @Vincent I am also facing the same issue. Can you share more details on how the issue was fixed?